# Minimum VLC Demo with HIP for Linux (HIPL)

Tags: ubuntu, vlc

I am new to HIPL and I am trying to set up a minimum demo with VLC 2.0.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed all the dependencies, and built from source (./configure && make && sudo make install). hipd was started on both server and client (which are all on a same ethernet router).

And I follow the instruction on:
http://infrahip.hiit.fi/hipl/manual/HOWTO.html#sec_vlc
I have some problem getting HIT address, "hipconf get ha default" does not return an address to me, so I use the IPv6 address from the interface dummy0 (presumably this is HIT, right?). But I cannot see video from client.

Can any one help and explain?

Thanks a lot.